# Apex:commandButton parameter was not sent to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I was not able to send a param from my VisualForce page to my controller.
 My code is as the following:

```
<apex:form id="commandForm">
  <apex:inputFile value="{!imageToReplace}" filename="{!imageNameToReplace}"  />
   <apex:commandButton action="{!replaceDocument}"  value="REPLACE IMAGE" id="theButton" >
      <apex:param name="documentId" assignTo="{!documentId}" value="{!s.Id}" />
  </apex:commandButton>
</apex:form>
```

Best Regards

Comment: I do not see any code :)

Comment: I put it but they don't appear

Comment: <apex:form id="commandForm">
        <apex:inputFile value="{!imageToReplace}" filename="{!imageNameToReplace}"  />
              <apex:commandButton action="{!replaceDocument}"  value="REPLACE IMAGE" id="theButton" >
                      <apex:param name="documentId" assignTo="{!documentId}" value="{!s.Id}" />
              </apex:commandButton>
  </apex:form>

Comment: You should use rerender attribute in apex:commandButton for the apex:param under it to pass value to controller.

Comment: Are you trying to assign `documentId` value into `s.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute `rerender` in your command button. for example `rerender  ="none"` . This is the key.

Becauuse you areusing inputfile so another option use apex:inputhidden.

```
<apex:inputhidden value="{!contVariable}" id="theinputhidden" />
```

Set this field value using javascript and then get this value in controller and use it.

Comment: But it can't be done when there is an inputFile in same force. Since it will throw the following error :
apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

Comment: It didn't work also.
</script>var theField = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theinputhidden}');</script>

    <apex:form >
    <apex:inputFile value="{!imageToReplace}" filename="{!imageNameToReplace}" />
     <apex:commandButton action="{!replaceDocument}" onclick="theField.value='0154B000000DGE1QAO';" value="REPLACE IMAGE" styleClass="save-btn" id="theButton" >
    <apex:param name="documentId" assignTo="{!documentId}" value="{!s.Id}" />
     </apex:commandButton> 
  <apex:inputhidden value="{!documentId}" id="theinputhidden" />  
    </apex:form>

Comment: did you check that your value set in inputHidden field.

Comment: yes and it was set but in controller it arrived null

Comment: so your javascript was not working correctly. Please check your code and your problem will be solved.

Comment: The inputHidden  value was sent in case I limit the result to 1 record in my apex:repeat howver in case of multiple record the value is null. any idea on that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:form id="commandForm">
  <apex:inputFile value="{!imageToReplace}" filename="{!imageNameToReplace}"  />
<Apex:Actionregion id="regionId">   
<apex:commandButton action="{!replaceDocument}" rerender="regionId"  value="REPLACE IMAGE" id="theButton" >
      <apex:param name="documentId" assignTo="{!documentId}" value="{!s.Id}" />
  </apex:commandButton>
</apex:ActionRegion>
</apex:form>
```

Place  your commandbutton inside the actionRegion tag and use rerender attribute on the commandbutton. It will resolve the error for the input file exception and also pass your parameter.

Comment: After applying your suggestion the apex:commandButton stops working.

Comment: Hey, It should work. I tried the same code and it worked for me. Can you check in the debug log whether the method is called or not?